# How to get a div with z-index to overlay another div on hover

Tags: css, hover, position, z-index

I have a container `div` with several smaller `div`:s inside, all of them with `float:left;`. If I hover one of the smaller `div`:s the `height` and `width` should be increased and it should overlay the other `div`:s without moving them.

HTML:

```
 <div id="boxcontainer">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  margin:5px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#boxcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width:500px;
  height:auto;
}

.box:hover {
  z-index:100;
  width:300px;
  height:auto;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Its not possible having this functionaluty with float:left and :hover psuedo class.
retaining the position of other boxes is only possible by position:absolute.
so use of  javascript and position:absolute is inevitable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**z-index only works on positioned elements** *(position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)*.

Instead of float left try position absolute.

I have added a container around each box and positioned each element absolutely within it. This way you can add as many boxes as you wish and keep the same class.

### EXAMPLE

**HTML**

```
<div id="boxcontainer">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="Inside"></div> 
    </div>         
    <div class="box">
        <div class="Inside"></div> 
    </div>         
    <div class="box">
        <div class="Inside"></div> 
    </div>     
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#boxcontainer{
    position: relative;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
.box{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin:5px;
}
.Inside{    
    background:green;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.Inside:hover{
    z-index:100;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    background:#666666;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JJ3v4/3/

Comment: Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/caniball/JJ3v4/

thank u in advance - seems this z-index-property is a little tricky...

Comment: Try my changes above. I think it is what you are trying to achieve. Don't forget to upvote if it's helpful.

Comment: Hey, thank you! I think this is the best solution to achieve - only using CSS. My Problem was, that die "box"-DIVs will be dropped into the page, using a WebYep-Loog - so i wanted them all to have the same class-name, cause i don´t know how many of them will be there in the future. But i guess i will go with your solution and rethink the loop-Element.

thanks a lot!

edit: damn, need more Reputation for an upvote - will do it later!

Comment: but if i Loop this boxes, let´s say there will be 6 of them - i gotte Name them box1, box2, box3, box4 and so on...? so i have to Change my Stylesheet depending on how many boxes there are...

instead of the different box-names, could the same solution be achieved using the "child"-selector ?

Comment: Forget my last suggestion. Now I know what your requirements are I have changed my answer where the same class is used. Check it out.

Comment: just deleted my last comment for this one:

holy sh*t :) that´s it!! thank you so much!
will voteup as soon as i have my 15 Reputation...you´re awesome!

Comment: Hey there, so playing basketball gets me a better vote :) haha...

Maybe you can help me with my next problem too - 
I wanted to rotate these boxes - this works, but as soon as they are rotated, the z-index stops working - any idea?

here´s a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/caniball/5KJG3/

for rotation - outcomment the css orders...

cheers

Comment: If you create a new question I will tell you the answer :)

Comment: I want to kiss you. I never knew that z-index didn't have any effect on non-positioned elements. You have no idea how much crappy CSS you helped me just dump.

Answer (score 1):

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hKL4f/1/

I think the easiest way to do what you want would be to use a CSS transform.

```
.box:hover {
    transform: scale(2, 2);
}
```

That way you alter the dimensions of the element on hover without affecting any of the other elements in the document flow around it.

If you want the boxes to expand in a different way (ie, to the right and bottom rather than in all directions) you can set a [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property (default is 50% 50%).

Comment: This pretty much Looks like what i want to achieve...but the "box"-DIVs will contain different Content, so they should expand depending on the Content...which isn´t the case with scale i guess?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...works somewhat

```
     .box{
   float:left;
 postion: fixed;
 width:150px;
 height:150px ; 
 margin:5px;
 background-color: yellow;
 }

 #boxcontainer{
 postion: fixed;
 width:500px;
 height:auto;
 }

 .box:hover{
 z-index:1;
 width:260px;
height:160px;
 position:absolute;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the Same problem in my project when i hover , the box changes its width and height but it efffects the other boxes as well so to solve this problem best way is to use `transform` property as below

```
.box:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2 , 1.2);  // This increses the dimmensions of the box and overlay 
                                       to others boxes without disturbing others  
}
```